APK is not working after I generated the APK from IONIC cordova
Screen shot of the APP I have built the IONIC App for generating the APK , the generation of APK is successful.But When I debug the APP I see an issue which I am not able to resolve.
I have generated build with ionic cordova build android which was successful, and then opened the project in Android studio and generated the build again, installed itin Android and started debugging
I need some asistance in solving this issue. Please help me run the APP successfully and let me know my mistakes if any.
